# Running a quarkus main (command line like) from an AWS lambda handler method

Tags: quarkus

I have a quarkus-camel batch application that needs to run under a lambda in AWS. This is working fine with pure java and spring-boot.
I need to be able to start the Quarkus Application from the AWS lambda handler method.
Running in batch works fine, but under lambda I get the following error:

**Caused by: io.quarkus.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Failed to determine the Maven artifact associated with the application /var/task**

This is the main java class. I need to know what to do in the handleRequest method to start the Quarkus (CAMEL) application.

```
package com.example;

import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain;
import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus;
import io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusApplication;

import io.quarkus.arc.Arc;
import io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusApplication;
import org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.CamelRuntime;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;


@QuarkusMain
public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Quarkus.run(CamelApp.class, args);
    }

    public static class CamelApp implements QuarkusApplication {

        @Inject
        ProducerTemplate camelProducer;

        @Inject
        CamelContext camelContext;

        @Override
        public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Hello Camel");
            CamelRuntime runtime = Arc.container().instance(CamelRuntime.class).get();
            runtime.start(args);
            camelProducer.sendBody("direct:lambda", "how about this?");

            return runtime.waitForExit();
        }
    }

    public Object handleRequest(final Object input, final Context context) {
        logger.info("input: {}", gson.toJson(input));
        logger.info("context: {}", gson.toJson(context));
        Quarkus.run(CamelApp.class);
        // CamelRuntime runtime = Arc.container().instance(CamelRuntime.class).get();
        // runtime.start(new String[] {"A","B","C"});
        // camelProducer.sendBody("direct:lambda", "how about this?");
        // runtime.waitForExit();
        return input;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ever get this working?